# How to update existing Object within Observable Array in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Ionic 5 / Angular app, I am trying to update a `Conversation` object within the below `Conversation` array:

```
private _conversations = new BehaviorSubject<Conversation[]>([
    new Conversation(
      'conversation1',
      'user3',
      'user1',
      [
        new Message('message1', 'Test message', 'user3', new Date(2018, 0O5, 0O5, 17, 23, 42, 11)),
        new Message('message2', 'Another message', 'user1', new Date(2018, 0O6, 0O5, 17, 23, 42, 11))
      ]),
    new Conversation(
      'conversation2',
      'user4',
      'user2',
      [
        new Message('message3', 'my  message', 'user4', new Date(2018, 0O7, 0O7, 17, 23, 42, 11)),
        new Message('message4', 'more messages', 'user2', new Date(2018, 0O7, 0O7, 17, 23, 42, 11)),
      ])
  ]);
```

Here are the `Conversation` & `Message` models I'm using:

```
export class Conversation {
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public userId: string,
        public mechanicId: string,
        public messages: Message[]
    ) { }
}

export class Message {
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public text: string,
        public userId: string,
        public timestamp: Date
    ) { }
}
```

I'm able to add to the array using these methods below:

```
addConversation(mechanicId: string, message: string) {
    const newConversation = new Conversation(
      Math.random().toString(),
      this.authService.userId,
      mechanicId,
      [this.createMessage(message)]
    );
    return this.conversations.pipe(
      take(1),
      delay(1000),
      tap(conversations => {
        this._conversations.next(conversations.concat(newConversation));
      }));
  }

  private createMessage(message: string): Message {
    return {
      id: Math.random().toString(),
      text: message,
      userId: this.authService.userId,
      timestamp: new Date(Date.now())
    };
  }
```

But I'm unable to update a `Conversation` (i.e. Add a new `Message` object to an existing `Conversation` object).

Here is my latest attempt:

```
addToConversation(id: string, mechanicId: string, message: string) {
    const conversation = this.getConversation(id);
    if (conversation) {
      conversation.messages.push(
        this.createMessage(message)
      );
    }
  }
```

This doesn't work however, as I get the following error message on `conversation.messages.push`:

> Property 'messages' does not exist on type Observable<{ id: string,
>   userId: string, mechanicId: string, messages: Message[]; }>

Also, here is `getConversation()`:

```
getConversation(id: string) {
    return this.conversations.pipe(
      take(1),
      map(conversations => {
        return { ...conversations.find(conversation => conversation.id === id) };
      }));
  }

get conversations() {
    return this._conversations.asObservable();
  }
```

Comment: Could you please show the `getConversation(id)` function?

Comment: Hi @MichaelD Thanks, added it above.

Comment: Also it isn't exactly clear how the `this.conversations` variable is defined.

Comment: Updated my question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need access to the current value of the Behavior subject, you could use the [`getValue()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5baa104cb47c924623076429366231d46952f545/src/internal/BehaviorSubject.ts#L32) method. It returns the current value held by the behavior subject. Using `pipe`, `map` and `take(1)` looks overkill to me. Try the following

```js
getConversation(id: string) {
  return this._conversations.getValue().find(conversation => conversation.id === id);
}

addMessageToConversation(conversationId: string, message: Message) {
  this.getConverstation().messages.push(message);
}
```

Then call the `addMessageToConversation()` function anywhere in the code

```js
addToConversation(id: string, mechanicId: string, message: string) {
  this.addMessageToConversation(id, this.createMessage(message));
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. What I want to do is when `addToConversation()` is called, push a `Message` object into the existing `Message[]` that's inside that `Conversation.`

Comment: You mean the newly created `Conversation` object?

Comment: The `Conversation ` that will be referenced in `addToConversation()` will always be pre-existing. Reason is that `addToConversation()` is called from inside a `Conversation-Detail` component (displaying existing messages), so the `Conversation` will always exist beforehand

Comment: I've edited the code. Please see if it works for you. Also I don't understand why you are returning a value from the `addToConversation()` function and what is the purpose of `concat` here.

Comment: To be honest, I am following along a Udemy tutorial & applying the code to fit my solution. From what I remember, `concat` was to add a newly created Conversation to `Conversation`s. That's working fine so I didn't ask that in the question. As for returning the Observable, I think it was something to do with maintaining state

Comment: So this code is executed on the `Conversation-Detail` page that displays a list of `Message`s associated with a `Conversation`. When I enter text & execute `addToConversation()`, navigate away from `Conversation-Detail` & navigate back, the new message is displayed alongside the others. But I want the list to update without me having to leave the page. I think this may have something to do with how the code is structured. What do you think?

Comment: Is there any way to use the existing `getConversation()` to do this?

Comment: I am afraid restructuring the code is beyond the scope of this question. And also navigation away and back is related to `Conversation-Detail` component and it is separate question. If this solution worked for this question, you are free to use it and create a new question for the other problem. If so, please don't forget to provide the code of `Conversation-Detail` component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211316/discussion-between-user9847788-and-michael-d).

Answer (score 0):

In-stream of data you can't modify the object. You have to create(emit) a new data. Here, in your case You create/push new data using

`observer.next(conversation)` and `takeLast(1)` instead of `take(1)`
takeLast will get the latest value always.

sample:

```
addToConversation(id: string, mechanicId: string, message: string) {
  const conversation = this.getConversation(id);
  if (conversation) {
    conversation.messages.push(
      this.createMessage(message)
    );
  this._conversations.next(conversation)
  }

}
```

Get Last:

```
getConversation(id: string) {
    return this.conversations.pipe(
      takeLast(1),
      map(conversations => {
        return { ...conversations.find(conversation => conversation.id === id) };
      }));
  }
```

Whole code:

```
export class Conversation {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public userId: string,
    public mechanicId: string,
    public messages: Message[]
  ) {}
}

export class Message {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public text: string,
    public userId: string,
    public timestamp: Date
  ) {}
}
class X {
  private messages = [
    new Conversation("conversation1", "user3", "user1", [
      new Message(
        "message1",
        "Test message",
        "user3",
        new Date(2018, 0o5, 0o5, 17, 23, 42, 11)
      ),
      new Message(
        "message2",
        "Another message",
        "user1",
        new Date(2018, 0o6, 0o5, 17, 23, 42, 11)
      ),
    ]),
    new Conversation("conversation2", "user4", "user2", [
      new Message(
        "message3",
        "my  message",
        "user4",
        new Date(2018, 0o7, 0o7, 17, 23, 42, 11)
      ),
      new Message(
        "message4",
        "more messages",
        "user2",
        new Date(2018, 0o7, 0o7, 17, 23, 42, 11)
      ),
    ]),
  ];
  private _conversations = new BehaviorSubject<Conversation[]>(this.messages);
  addToConversation(id: string, mechanicId: string, message: string) {
    const conversation = this.messages.find((conversation) => conversation.id === id)
    if (conversation) {
      conversation.messages.push(this.createMessage(message));
    }
    this._conversations.next(conversation)
  }
  addConversation(mechanicId: string, message: string) {
    const newConversation = new Conversation(
      Math.random().toString(),
      this.authService.userId,
      mechanicId,
      [this.createMessage(message)]
    );
    return this.conversations.pipe(
      takeLast(1),
      delay(1000),
      tap((conversations) => {
        this._conversations.next(conversations.concat(newConversation));
      })
    );
  }
  getConversation(id: string) {
    return this.conversations.pipe(
      take(1),
      map((conversations) => {
        return {
          ...conversations.find((conversation) => conversation.id === id),
        };
      })
    );
  }

  get conversations() {
    return this._conversations.asObservable();
  }
  private createMessage(message: string): Message {
    return {
      id: Math.random().toString(),
      text: message,
      userId: this.authService.userId,
      timestamp: new Date(Date.now()),
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but I am getting this error message under conversation.messages.push: 

Property 'messages' does not exist on type Observable<{ id: string, userId: string, mechanicId: string, messages: Message[]; }>

Comment: Also this error appeared under this._conversations.next(conversation)

Argument of type Observable<{ id: string, userId: string, mechanicId: string, messages: Message[]; }> is not assignable to parameter of type 'Conversation[]'

Comment: i though know basic coding! i just suggest how you should do, not exact code! lol. let me update my answer!

Comment: Oh OK. If you could, could you please use the existing `getConversation()` please?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem , change the  `Message` model and change `createMessage` function

```
    class Message {
    public id: string
    public text: string
    public userId: string
    public timestamp: Date
    constructor(
        options: any = {}
    ) {
        this.id = options.id || '';
        this.text = options.text || '';
        this.userId = options.userId || '';
        this.timestamp = options.timestamp || null; // null or new Date()
    }
}

private createMessage(message: string): Message {
    return new Message({
      id: Math.random().toString(),
      text: message,
      userId: this.authService.userId,
      timestamp: new Date(Date.now())
    });
  }
```

if not, let me know